# Hadoop client Username and Password access problem to the Azure Data Lake Gen2

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake

Trying to connect to Azure Data Lake storage Gen2 using a Username and Password authentication type via Hadoop client in console and receive the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.consumeInputStream(AzureADAuthenticator.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenSingleCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.UserPasswordTokenProvider.refreshToken(UserPasswordTokenProvider.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AccessTokenProvider.getToken(AccessTokenProvider.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAccessToken(AbfsClient.java:546)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.executeHttpOperation(AbfsRestOperation.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getFilesystemProperties(AbfsClient.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getIsNamespaceEnabled(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:2016)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:390)
```

What was done:

1. Created Storage account using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-quickstart-create-account
2. Created Azure AD application using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal
3. Add AD user to the storage account as a STORAGE BLOB DATA OWNER in the Access control (IAM).

According to the [Apache documentation](https://aajisaka.github.io/hadoop-document/hadoop-project/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0:_Username_and_Password) I created a console command

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.azure.ssl.channel.mode=Default_JSSE
-Dfs.azure.account.auth.type=OAuth
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.UserPasswordTokenProvider
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.user.name=<USER_NAME@mail.com>
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.user.password=<PASSWORD>
-ls abfss://<CONTAINER NAME>@<STORAGE ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

If try to use this endpoint

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

the output is

```
ls: AADToken: HTTP connection failed for getting token from AzureAD. Http response: 400 Bad Request
```

So the command below should display a list of the folders and files in the container. Something wrong with the command or with a container configuration in Azure? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using an Azure AD User or a Service Principal you must use the OAuth2 V1 token endpoint as it's the supported by the Authenticator class. This is the token endpoint URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token
```

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-ad-endpoint-v1-vs-v2/) you can find the difference between the V1 and V2 endpoints.

That being said, the console command you must use becomes:

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.azure.ssl.channel.mode=Default_JSSE \
-Dfs.azure.account.auth.type=OAuth \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.UserPasswordTokenProvider \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.user.name={USER_NAME@mail.com} \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.user.password={PASSWORD} \
-ls abfss://{CONTAINER NAME}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

According to your question it seems like you might want to authenticate using a service principal as well, in that case you must use  *ClientCredsTokenProvider* instead of *UserPasswordTokenProvider* as shown below:

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.azure.ssl.channel.mode=Default_JSSE \
-Dfs.azure.account.auth.type=OAuth \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id={CLIENT_ID} \
-Dfs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret={SECRET_KEY} \
-ls abfss://{CONTAINER NAME}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

You could also store the auth info in the core-site.xml file as it's explained on the [hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0_Client_Credentials). In the case you want to use multiple storage accounts you can change the property name to end with the dfs endpoint as shown in the next example:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.auth.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>OAuth</value>
  <description>
  Use OAuth authentication
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider</value>
  <description>
  Use client credentials
  </description>
</property>
<property
  <name>fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token</value>
  <description>
  URL of OAuth endpoint
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>{CLIENT_ID}</value>
  <description>
  Client ID
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>{SECRET_KEY}</value>
  <description>
  Secret
  </description>
</property>
```

Sorry if it's too late, I just ran across this problem and this question was in the path to find a solution, when I got it to work I thought someone might find this helpful.